# Checking message length with Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make it so the bot replies something when a message length is above 120 characters
here's my code so far

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if #here I'm trying to make the thing I just described
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Do you know how to check the length of a string? `message.clean_content` will return a string. Try using these two pieces of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the message length via `len(message.clean_content)`:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if len(message.clean_content) > 20:
        #do stuff here
```

Clean content is used here, because it returns the message content as the client shows it, for example `<#id>` will transform into `#name`. If you want to get the message length the way discord counts it, use `message.content`

---

**References:**

- [Message.clean_content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.clean_content)

Answer (score 1):

Accodring to the [doco](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.content), you should be able to use `message.content` to get the contents of a message as a `str`. Then, it is just a matter of having a comparison:

```
if len(message.content) > 120:
    #reply to message here
```

As noted above, you can also use `message.clean_content`.